# SQL recursivo usando CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou montando uma instrução SQL usando [CTE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (expressão de tabela comum) e recursividade, porém estou tendo o seguinte erro:

> Mensagem 530, Nível 16, Estado 1, Linha 5 A instrução foi encerrada. A
>   recursão máxima 100 se exauriu antes do fim da instrução.

**Versão do SQL Server:**

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-GDR) (KB3210089) - 13.0.4202.2 (X64)
>   Dec 13 2016 05:22:44   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise
>   Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard
>   6.3  (Build 14393: )

Segue exemplo que montei que reproduz o comportamento da minha consulta

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DADOS
CREATE TABLE #DADOS (
    ID INTEGER,
    DATA DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #DADOS VALUES(1, '01/09/2007')
INSERT INTO #DADOS VALUES(2, '01/09/2016')

GO

WITH V_DADOS
    AS( SELECT  *
        FROM    (
                  SELECT  ID, 
                        DATA,                         
                          CASE WHEN MONTH(DATA) <= MONTH(GETDATE())  THEN 
                              CAST('01/'+CAST(DATEPART(MM,DATA) AS VARCHAR)+'/'+CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,DATEADD(YEAR,1,GETDATE()))AS VARCHAR) AS DATE) 
                          ELSE
                               CAST('01/'+CAST(DATEPART(MM,DATA) AS VARCHAR)+'/'+CAST(DATEPART(YYYY,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) AS DATE) 
                          END AS DATA_MAX                          
                  FROM    #DADOS
                ) SUB
        WHERE   ID = 1
        AND     SUB.DATA < SUB.DATA_MAX
        UNION   ALL
        SELECT  ID,
                DATEADD(M,1,DATA) DATA,                
                DATA_MAX
        FROM    V_DADOS     
        WHERE   DATA < DATA_MAX     
    )

    SELECT  ID, DATA, DATA_MAX
    FROM    V_DADOS
```

A ideia da recursividade é completar uma tabela de parcelas que temos no sistema, hoje já existe uma procedure com uma consulta recursiva seguindo a mesma lógica do exemplo que adicionei.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado na realidade avança de mês em mês até `01/09/2019` e seriam pelos meus cálculos uns 140 meses que deveriam ser retornados pela consulta

Comment: Sim, depois eu reparei que havia lido o `DATEADD` erroneamente, é tanto que removi meu comentário anterior. A propósito, fazer uma recursão de 100+ níveis em SQL normalmente é um _bad smell_. Isso parece-me algo muito mais imperativo do que declarativo, então eu particularmente creio que essa solução está usando chaves de fenda para fixar um prego.

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado é bem isso que vc disse `uma chave de fenda para fixar um prego`, mas já existe uma procedure com esse select recursivo, não estou criando esse monstro do zero, então por hora só vou arrumar o necessário para conseguir executar a procedure e resolver um problema pontual que tenho. Vc já deve ter trabalhando em sistemas legados e deve saber como é mexer nessas procedures mágicas criadas por outros devs.

Comment: Se você explicar o resultado exato que você quer, juntamente com os dados de origem, podemos te indicar uma solução que realmente atenda ao que você precisa, agrida menos o banco de dados e seja de fácil compreensão

Comment: @Sorack a questão toda é que hoje já existe uma procedure cheia de regras de negócio dentro dela, eu montei só um exemplo com a lógico do problema que estava tendo dentro dessa procedure, hoje não me sinto confortável em mexer nessa procedure, pois não sei o impacto para todo o sistema, mas certamente tetaria ao máximo evitar essa recursividade, mas como o negócio já tá feito, vou só corrigir o que preciso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na utilização de `CTE` precisa de ter certos cuidados, principalmente na possibilidade de entrar em *loop* infinito.

Pode definir o máximo de recursividade de uma CTE, utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
-- definir o limite de recursão para 1.000
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000)

-- remover o limite de recursão
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo, valeu pela resposta